# Does sun-exposure correlate positively with sex drive?

Tags: sun, sex

There are many [sites](https://citymagazine.si/en/in-these-countries-women-have-the-strongest-and-wildest-sexual-libido-and-where-are-the-slovenian-women/) posting kinda this:

> A study by Victoria Milan - a dating site for married and committed people looking to have an affair - looked at the profiles of its millions of active members from 20 countries to find out where in the world the most sexually active women are - and how they look to your sex drive. According to the mentioned study, Scandinavian women have the highest sex drive in the world. Ladies from Finland (79 %), Sweden (78 %), Denmark (76 %) and Norway (76 %) admit they love sex - what else to do when it's cold and dark for six months of the year.

On the other hand we have [this](https://www.earth.com/news/exposure-to-sunlight-enhances-libido/):

> A team of researchers from Tel Aviv University recently discovered that exposure to ultraviolet radiation from sunlight enhances sex drive in both men and women by affecting the regulation of the endocrine system, which is responsible for producing and releasing sexual hormones.

Well, Scandinavian countries are among those with less Sunshine compared to countries that are nearer to the Equator.

Which claim is false here?

Comment: This is not an either/or situation. They can both be correct (or both false)

Comment: The Victoria Milan's study should have included a season of the year, summers in Tel Aviv are hot and humid so many people stay inside while in Scandinavia summers are moderate with a lot of sunlight hours so people stay out more which might explain the consequences

Comment: Unless the Tel Aviv study claims that UV is the only or dominant factor in determining sex drive, there is no contradiction here - maybe the "ladies from Finland" mentioned in the first quote would have an *even higher* sex drive if more regularly exposed to UV light. That leaves us with a question which is examining two unrelated claims, which doesn't fit the format of the site.

Comment: I think  "Scandinavian countries [have] less sunshine" in the winter, but more sunshine in the summer.  (Measured in hours per day.)

Comment: There are other factors that are wastly more likely to influence sex drive than sunlight (if even significant), for instance [general happiness in society](https://worldhappiness.report/ed/2022/happiness-benevolence-and-trust-during-covid-19-and-beyond/). Out of 146 countries: `1. Finland (7.821) 2. Denmark (7.636) ... 7. Sweden (7.384) 8. Norway (7.365)`

Comment: That first link does not really suggest anything about the sex drive of women in Scandinavia.  What they report is that more than 75% or Scandinavian women **believe that their sex drive is higher than other women's sex drive**.  Which, if this tells us anything, it might be that women in Scandinavia appear to other women to be less sexually active than they actually are.  Even this seems unlikely though, because the "study" appears to be an analysis of dating profiles.  So maybe it's just telling us these women believe that men are more interested in women with higher sex drives.

Comment: "Scandinavian women [...] admit they love sex" could just be a reflection on how open Scandinavian women are in talking about sex and their desires for it.